# Airport meet up during transit

Tags: transit, airports, doha

I live in UAE and one of my friends is travelling from USA to India with transit at Doha international airport. He wants to meet me at the airport during his transit. I assume that he will be not leaving the transit area since he has a flight to catch for India and he will already have a boarding pass provided at checkin at USA.

How do I travel to Doha airport (fly to Doha) to meet him while he is in transit? I would be only at Doha airport till my return flight. How can I maximize the time that we have to meet during his transit?

Comment: Airport maps are at https://dohahamadairport.com/airport-guide/at-the-airport/maps or https://www.doh-airport.com/en. It appears that all gates are in one security zone, so there are not issues with having to exit security and reenter.

Comment: The way you maximize your time together is for each of you to schedule the longest layover possible.  Otherwise I'm still not clear what your basic question is...

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

**A) Meet landside**

In this case you both will have to go through immigration and exit the secure area. You will need both full access credentials for Doha. Your friend will NOT have to collect bags, as they are checked through (assuming they travel on a single ticket).

You can meet in the arrival area or, given enough time, you can actually take transportation into town and hang out wherever you feel like. Doha is nice !

You will have to clear security again, when you go back to your gates.

**B) Meet airside**

For your friend this is very straight forward: they exit the plane, follow "connecting flights" go through security and are then in the airside terminal. That's the same procedure whether they meet with you or not.

Your trip is a little more complicated. Make sure you have boarding passes for both legs of your trip before you start. You should be able to check in online. If you have to go to a check in counter, they should be able to give you both boarding passes.

On arrival you can either go to the exit or to "connecting flights". Doha has security for all passengers going to connecting flights. I believe that they do check your connecting boarding pass at this point. They may or may not accept your return boarding pass at this point. If they don't, you have to exit through immigration (requiring full Qatar access credentials) turn around, go through exit immigration and security to go back into the terminal.

Once you are in the terminal area you can meet with your friend wherever you want. I believe Doha has only a single terminal and all the concourses are connected airside but this type of information is not very easy to confirm. If you want to be sure, book your flight with the same airline (or alliance) as your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with the airport at Doha.

If the two travelers' flights arrive at the same Doha Terminal or Concourse, they can meet within that Terminal or Concourse's Transit area.

If, however, the two travelers' flights arrive at different Terminals or Concourses, then the travelers may find themselves in different transit areas. In this situation, the travelers can only meet if there is an airside connection between the two Terminals' or Concourses' airside spaces. Some airports provide these connections (which may be pedestrian or by tram or bus) and some airports do not.